# Django converting tiff to jpeg with pillow

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, tiff, libtiff

I'm working with Django in Python 3, and I have a model with an `ImageField` and I'm trying to override the `.save()` to do tiff to jpeg conversion:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

class MyModel(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_to, editable=True, null=True, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pil_image_obj = Image.open(self.image)
        new_image_io = BytesIO()
        rgb_pil_image_obj = pil_image_obj.convert("RGB")
        rgb_pil_image_obj.save(new_image_io, quality=90, format='JPEG')

        # temp_name = self.image.name
        # self.image.delete(save=False)

        # self.image.save(
        #     temp_name,
        #     content=ContentFile(new_image_io.getvalue()),
        #     save=False
        # )

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, this leads to:

```
tempfile.tif: Cannot read TIFF header.
*** OSError: -2
```

If I try the save experiment but only opening the TIFF file from disk instead of feeding `PIL.Image` with the Django `InMemoryUploadedFile`, then everything works absolutely fine and the tiff is converted to a jpeg.

Also `pil_image_obj.verify()` doesn't throw any exceptions.

I'm using `Pillow==5.3.0`

What could be the issue? And is there any other way to do such a conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path of the image file to `Image.open()`. Currently you're passing the field itself.

```
pil_image_obj = Image.open(self.image.path)  # Pass the path
```

Comment: I am using s3 and django storages, and doing as you suggested gives `*** NotImplementedError: This backend doesn't support absolute paths.`. I think loading `self.image` the in memory content file should be working

Comment: Ok I didn't realise you were using s3

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that. But still I'd like to know why this fails for an `InMempryUploadedFile`, since it doesn't raise any Pillow errors, even with `verify()`. Most things seem possible except this tiff headers issue on save. I'm also open to any other ideas for converting tiffs on the fly before the upload/save.